# How to understand the script conlleval.perl for evaluating tagging?

Tags: perl, sequence, precision, tagging

I always don't know how to evaluate a task for tagging including POS tagging or any other sequence tagging. I especially don't know how to calculate the Precision, Recall and F1 score of those tasks. 
I then found there is a script named conlleval.perl and we can directly use it for evaluating. But I don't know perl language and I still confused how P, R, F1 calculated in tagging tasks.
Is there anyone can tell me?

Comment: Is there a question here?  Maybe if you showed some code.

Comment: There is no question in the code. I just don't know how to understand the calculation of Precision, Recall and F1 score when evaluate the B-I-O sequence tagging.

Comment: Maybe a link to the script?  Otherwise, there is no way to clarify the calculations for you.

Comment: well, sorry. Here is a link. [link](https://github.com/robertostling/efselab/blob/master/3rdparty/conlleval.perl)

Comment: Do you need to know the formulas used?  Or the motivation?

Comment: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/papers/RatinovRo09.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

Comment: I know the formulas used in Presicion, Recall and F1 score for classification task. But in sequence tagging task in nueral language processing like slot filling using B-I-O tags I am confused how to understand it.  I can simply explain the task: a sentence like "I want to fly from Beijing to New York." can be tagged as "O O O O O B_from_loc O B_to_loc I_to_loc" in which 'O' means 'other tag' and tags begin with 'B' and 'I' means the beginning and inter- of a named tag like from_location or to_location respectively.  Should I regard this as a multi-classification problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple definition in a book *Spoken Language Understanding: Systems for Extracting Semantic Information from Speech* (by Gokhan Tur, Renato De Mori), [chapter 3.1.5 Evaluation metrics](https://books.google.pl/books?id=RDLyT2FythgC&lpg=RA1-PT35&dq=precision%20and%20recall%20for%20slot%20detection&hl=pl&pg=RA1-PT36#v=onepage&q=precision%20and%20recall%20for%20slot%20detection&f=false):

*Precision = # of reference slots correctly detected by SLU / # of total slots detected by SLU*

*Recall = # of reference slots correctly detected by SLU / # of total reference slots*

*F1 = 2 x Precision x Recall / (Precision + Recall)*

Note: for overall metrics *conlleval* uses [micro averaging](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/16001/20395).